# Can the way Sublime Text 2 auto encloses selections in pairs be changed?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2 you can type a string and then highlight some section of the string like the following:

[image]

Then you can enclose the selected text in " by just typing a single " which gives you this:

[image]

When you do that the cursor ends up between d and ", I'd really like it to end up outside of the " at the end of the selected string.

[image]

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a feature I use, but the following seems to work ok. Create a snippet like this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA["$SELECTION"$0]]></content>
</snippet>
```

The `$0` specifies the cursor exit point. Keybind it in your `/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap` file:

```
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", 
  "args": {"name": "Packages/User/quotes.sublime-snippet"}}
```

Comment: @fraxel May I ask you how did you manage to do that? Is there some detailed documentation?

Comment: @Qwerty - sure - read loads of docs, examples, and try stuff out.. ;) [these docs are ok](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html)